# How to reset/reload/restart a Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I would like to display a feedback google form in kiosk mode on a tablet. After form completion, it should show a "thank you" message and restart the form for the next visitor.

I noticed a "Show link to submit another response" in the form settings menu, but no way to accomplish a auto refresh.

Fortunately there is the google's script manager. As the script runs in a sandboxed iframe, I cant even access the window object. I know that I can access the [FormApp.getActiveForm()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#getactiveform) method, but there seem to be no way to reset/reload the form.

I can't think of another way doing it.

Comment: Browser add-on might help as they maybe able to access window. Alternatively, Your page can try loading the form in a iframe in your own html page. Once you receive a submit event, you may be able to refresh the iframe.

Comment: @TheMaster It's not possible to listen for a submit event on an iframe which loads from a foreign hostnamen.

Comment: May be check for change in src of iframe? If the url changes on submit, it should be easy to track based on that. Alternatively, submit event triggers a server event onFormSubmit, you can use that to reload.

Comment: @TheMaster It's not possible to access `iframe.contentWindow.location` due to cross origin issues. The same applies for all events except `onload` on the iframe itself.

Comment: But iframe src maybe accessible(I've tested long before and it was accessible). Regardless, even  if that's not possible, Like I said, you can use the [server event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) to force reloading the page.

Comment: Once detected in apps script, you may post that to your server, which will force client refresh.

Comment: @TheMaster the iframe src value does not change when the site within the iframe loads a different url. It does only change if you change it from parent window.

I can listen for the server submit event, true, but how do I reload the page within googles iframe sandbox? window.location is not available.

Comment: If your control the parent window, You can simply  load a new frame(remove the old frame) or change the iframe src to "" and then back to the Google forms. It's possible to navigate/ change the iframe from parent even if they're of different origin.

Comment: @TheMaster How do I know from the parent window that the form was submited? I can listen for the submit event, but only within the iframe using googles script manager. I see no way to let the parent window know about the submit event.

Comment: onFormSubmit is a server event. You can listen to it from anywhere and any script. Create a standalone Google script to listen to the event and then POST that information to your server controlling the parent. Alternatively, your parent window should poll the web-app(which your standalone Google script will offer https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)  to know when to reload.