# Custom Script to Force Google Form Back to Entry Page on Submit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I would like to use a Google Form as a sign-in and sign-out sheet on a single computer (kiosk style), and I am already aware of the built-in setting where once the form is submitted it gives the option to click to go back to a blank version of the form (so that someone else can make another entry). However, it would be handy to have a script that when the form was submitted it would automatically (without having to click) send the page back to a blank version of the form. Does anyone know a way to do this?

I did some research about how to possibly do this using openById or openByURL and kept getting an error that the function didn't exist. I then read on another StackOverflow question that for security reasons, Google removed these functions for use within a custom function.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To maximize the chance to have a valuable feedback, you should be more specific, show what you tried and explain what does not work. See [ask]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56462712/